# Getting all elements

Tags: java, xml, sax

I have an XML document, that looks like this (I know, it doesn't make sense, it's just an example):

```
<Person>
  <Name>Peter</Name>
  <Country>Sweden</Country>
  <Param name="Sport" value="yes"/>
  <Param name="Color" value="no"/>
<Person/>
```

It can have an infinit number of the element `Param`.
Getting the content of `Country` I do

```
String country = doc.getElementsByTagName("Country").item(0).getTextContent();
```

Getting the content of the first attribute `name` of the first `Param` I do

```
String name = source.getElementsByTagName("Param").item(0).getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue();
```

But how can I get all values of all the attributes of `Param`, without knowing how many elements of `Param` exist?

I need something like ("pseudo code"):

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

for(int i=0; i<=source.getElementsByTagName("Param").size(); i++){
  String name = source.getElementsByTagName("Param").item(i).getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue();
  String value = source.getElementsByTagName("Param").item(i).getAttributes().item(1).getNodeValue();

  hm.put(name, value);
}
```

Comment: Use dom4j to parse the XML document

Comment: Try using the code from my post should work. Use dom4j library for your xml parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask for an attribute by its name.

```
String attrName = source.getElementsByTagName("Param").item(i).getAttribute("name"));
String value = source.getElementsByTagName("Param").item(i).getAttribute("value"));
//you could test if the values are null
hm.put(attrName, value);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was just pseudo code. There is no size()-method in `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: There is a getLength() function on a node list

Answer (score 0):

```
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    Document document = reader.read("yourxmlfilehere(url, file)");
    root = document.getRootElement();
    root = root.element("Person");
    for(Iterator i = root.elementIterator("Param"); i.hasNext();)
    {
        Element e = (Element)i.next();
        hm.put(e.attributeValue("name"), e.attributeValue("value"));
    }
```